# android sqlite updates not showing in emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

Please bare with this noob question - I have an old project I'm trying to make very minor changes in quick time, so spending lots of time really understanding each function is not an option.

The app uses a sqlite db and I have made some minor changes directly using DB Browser for SQLite, however they are not showing up at all when I run the app in the emulator - still all the old content.

I have the db file in `/assets/content/app_data.sqlite`, the code to open the file is:

```
String _dbPath;
static String DATABASE_NAME = "app_data.sqlite";

_dbPath = String.format("%s/%s", context.getFilesDir(), DATABASE_NAME);
File dbFile = new File(_dbPath);
InputStream assetStream = context.getAssets().open("content/" + DATABASE_NAME);
```

When I step through this code, what is confusing me is what `_dbPath` is computing to: `/data/user/0/au.myapp/files/app_data.sqlite` - what does this mean in the context of where I'm editing the db ?

Is there a trick to have android pick up the db changes ? Is it cached somehow ? Any pointers much appreciated.

Comment: When you do some changes with SQLite then you have to remove your app and run it again so you new instance will be created when your re-install the app

Comment: not sure what you mean as I'm running it in emulator via android studio - so i'm stopping and starting it each time

Comment: i mean uninstall your app from emulator and run your project again

Comment: oh boy that fixed it - I cleared the AVD device and seems to have worked! Couldn't find that detail anywhere, thanks!